# Hypernym for plant, insect, and fungus

Tags: nouns, generic-term, biology

What noun encompasses all three of these: a plant, fungus, or insect.

Comment: I'm voting close this question because our help Center specifically states that choosing names for software related things is out of scope for our site.

Comment: If you could rework this question to make it not-about-databases, I'd suggest the word ***organism***

Comment: @JimMack That's the word.  Sorry that I didn't ask the question in the correct way!  I'll rework the question.

Comment: I doubt there is one. Plants and fungi are nonsentient. Insects are sentient.

Comment: Heh, is there a good place to ask for suggestions for naming software entities?  I'm *so* often hung up on that …